# LotusScript Function Doesn't Save Form Fields

Tags: function, lotus-notes, designer, lotusscript

Can anyone spot an obvious reason as to why my save function isn't saving the fields in my form? It saves the document, but the fields are empty when I open it up. The following code is what I'm using:

```
 Public Sub co_loopNamesAndSaveDocs()

'Dim variables  
 Dim s As New NotesSession
 Dim thisDatabase As NotesDatabase
 Set thisDatabase = s.CurrentDatabase
 Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
 Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Dim currentDoc As NotesDocument 
Set currentDoc = uidoc.Document
Dim newDoc As NotesDocument
Dim PersonNameField As NotesItem
Set PersonNameField = currentDoc.GetFirstItem("PersonName")

'Loop through values in PersonNameField and create a new document for each value found

Forall pName In PersonNameField.Values

Set newDoc = New NotesDocument (thisDatabase)
newDoc.Form="newLocationForm"
newDoc.StartDate = currentDoc.StartDate(0)
newDoc.EndDate = currentDoc.EndDate(0)
newDoc.Duration = currentDoc.Duration(0)
newDoc.StartTime = currentDoc.StartTime(0)
newDoc.EndTime = currentDoc.EndTime(0)
newDoc.Comments = currentDoc.Comments(0)
newDoc.Status = currentDoc.Status(0)
newDoc.LocationCode = currentDoc.LocationCode(0)
newDoc.PersonName = pName
Call newDoc.Save (True, False, False)

End Forall

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I don't see an obvious error in the coding, I'd say that the fields in newDoc are blank because the fields in currentDoc are blank.  And since currentDoc was set to uidoc.Document, that probably means that you have a synch problem between front-end and back-end documents. I.e., the values exist in your uidoc, but have not yet been saved to the back-end prior to calling this code.  If I'm right, try calling uidoc.save() before assigning currentDoc.  If you don't want to save to the back-end, then instead of using the back-end as your data source you should be using uidoc.fieldGetText("PersonName") and parsing out the values.